# javascript countdown clock

Tags: javascript, jquery

im trying to write a countdown clock to a certain day in js. I have the following which works if i output it to the page but I cant seem to write it to a div using innerhtml?

Can anybody see where im going wrong?

```
today = new Date();
expo = new Date("February 05, 2012");
msPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 ;
timeLeft = (expo.getTime() - today.getTime());
e_daysLeft = timeLeft / msPerDay;
daysLeft = Math.floor(e_daysLeft);
document.getElementById('cdown').innerHTML = document.write(daysLeft);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
document.getElementById('cdown').innerHTML = daysLeft
```

You don't need document.write

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `document.write(daysLeft)`, that will write `daysLeft` to the document, not the `div`! Just set `daysLeft`:

```
document.getElementById('cdown').innerHTML = daysLeft;
```

Answer (score 2):

on this line:

```
document.getElementById('cdown').innerHTML = document.write(daysLeft);
```

remove the `document.write(`. If you're setting the contents of an element, you don't need to write to the document as well.

Fixed code:

```
today = new Date();
expo = new Date("February 05, 2012");
msPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 ;
timeLeft = (expo.getTime() - today.getTime());
e_daysLeft = timeLeft / msPerDay;
daysLeft = Math.floor(e_daysLeft);
document.getElementById('cdown').innerHTML = daysLeft;
```